# jQuery mobile 1.4 not enhancing content added with knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, knockout.js, progressive-enhancement

I create a list of elements with a knockout.js 'foreach', and want these to be enhanced to jQuery mobile buttons.

```
  <div data-role="content" class="content">
     <div id="buttonContainer" data-bind="foreach: buttons">
        <div class="controllerButton" data-role="button">              
              <span class="buttonText" data-bind="text: label"></span>
        </div>
     </div>         
  </div>
```

Using jQuery mobile 1.3.2, this works fine. With the 1.4 alpha, jQuery mobile doesn't do anything to the elements.

(I'm aware I'm asking about an alpha without documentation, but certain features like panels outside of pages make the switch very attractive even at this point in time.)

Comment: `data-role=button`is deprecated as of 1.4 and will be removed on 1.5, replace it with `class="ui-btn"` this is the way of creating buttons in 1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of jQuery Mobile 1.4 `data-role=button` is deprecated and will be removed on 1.5. It is now replaced by adding classes directly to *anchor*. The main class is `ui-btn` which will convert an element into a button.

#### HTML

```html
<div data-role="content" class="content">
  <div id="buttonContainer" data-bind="foreach: buttons">
    <!-- adds button and icon classes -->
    <a class="controllerButton" data-bind="text: label, css: icon">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### JS

```
ko.applyBindings({
    buttons: [{
        "label": "One",
            "icon": "ui-btn ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-top"
    }, {
        "label": "Two",
            "icon": "ui-btn ui-icon-arrow-r ui-btn-icon-right"
    }, {
        "label": "Three",
            "icon": "ui-btn ui-icon-edit ui-btn-icon-bottom"
    }, {
        "label": "Four",
            "icon": "ui-btn ui-icon-info ui-btn-icon-left"
    }, {
        "label": "Five",
            "icon": "ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext"
    }]
});
```

> [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/mF84r/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the .refresh method on your buttons, after calling applyBindings.

In your case something like

```
...
ko.applyBindings()
$('.controllerButton').button('refresh');
```

http://api.jquerymobile.com/button/#method-refresh

Comment: The problem isn't re-applying the styling, it's that the elements are not set as buttons by jQuery mobile in the first place. Just tried it again, and it works fine as-is with jQuery mobile 1.3.2.